# Facebook Insights API not returning all values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Using the Facebok API Explorer I just get a few values back from Facebook. I have an app that calls this API as well. Last week this was working properly, getting all values described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

But now, here are the only values I'm getting back from Facebook:

- page_story_adds_unique (week)
- page_friends_of_fans (day)
- page_storytellers (week)
- page_admin_num_posts (week)
- page_admin_num_posts_by_type (day)
- page_admin_num_posts_by_type (week)

This is the request my app and the Facebook API is sending:
https://graph.facebook.com/115893033044/insights?method=GET&format=json&access_token=XXXX

Does anyone know what might be the problem? Thanks!

NOTE: This fan page has more than 30 likes.

Comment: I've same problem with my page. Have I resolved it in any way?

Comment: It seems to be that Facebook Insights API does not work properly all the time. I have filled a lot of tickets and still do it every week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a known bug at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/496912223696481?browse=search_51a3465d5abbf4197426907